# Wordpress Wampserver multiple computers

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wampserver, wordpress-login, wamp64

Does anyone know how I could work on one website with a friend on wordpress with 2 different computers?

What are the options, because we cant work on a localhost together because its local. What can I do so that we cam both login to the same wordpress accounts  on different computers to work simultaneously?

Both computers are windows operated

Comment: Huh! Im new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

connect both computer usiing lan cable. then assign ips to both computer after that install the wordpress using ip (if wampp is installed on 192.168.0.1) then hit the url http://192.168.0.1/wordpress/

and share the wordpress folder with your partner.

Comment: Hi Rajkumar, thanks for your help. Would you mind going into more detail for me please because im new to the process?

Comment: do you have switch to connect both computer using lan

Comment: if you have wifi router it also has 4 pin switch

Comment: Yeah I do, but I will have to buy lan cable

Comment: yes you have to....

Comment: Which ip adress do I assign? Any of the two?

Comment: 192.168.0.1  to 192.168.255.255

Comment: Okay and after that where would u suggest I share the wordpress folder?

Comment: yes and install your wordpress with   http:// your-ip/ wordpres not http://localhost/wordpress

Comment: Okay then, I will try this, so after this is done we will definitely be able to use the same login in wordpress to both work on our website?

Comment: yes then you cann access wordpress with same url

Comment: And also use the same login? Thats the most important haha

Comment: yes you can use same login

Comment: this is same as you host the site on server and any one who connected with this network can access the website

Comment: Thankyou so much rajkumar, I will try this and  if i get stuck will ask for your help again. Have a great day!